# Is a type conversion in a inner join safe if reliant on data/row filtering?

Tags: sql, inner-join, where-clause, optimizer-hints

If a join condition does data conversion that's only valid on some of the rows, but your where condition filters the rows to the "valid" rows is that a "safe" join condition?

I'm of the opinion it's not but I'm by no means and expert and am just trying to understand. AFAIK the optimizer can pretty much do whatever it wants as long as at the end of the day all the joins happened and all the conditions eventually get run.

I've tried googling this but haven't seen anything concrete

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS ID) a
       JOIN (SELECT '1' AS ID,
                    'Y' AS FILTER
             UNION
             SELECT 'NOT_AN_INT' AS ID,
                    'N'          AS FILTER) b
         ON a.ID = CONVERT(INT, b.ID)
 WHERE b.FILTER = 'Y' 


SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT 1 AS ID) a
       JOIN (SELECT '1' AS ID,
                    'Y' AS FILTER
             UNION
             SELECT 'NOT_AN_INT' AS ID,
                    'N'          AS FILTER) b
         ON a.ID = CONVERT(INT, b.ID)
            AND b.FILTER = 'Y'
```

As I understand it the join conditions should be commutative on an inner join and both of those queries should be equivalent to each other. However the second one blows up due to type coercion problems. Does that prove that this is bad practice and you should do the safe conversion of a's ID to a varchar instead of b's ID to an int? Or is there some ansi spec guaranteeing this is ok?

Comment: Will do thanks, but I want a dbms agnostic answer. Even if I can get away with doing it in a database, but it still goes against the spec I would still say it's best practice to avoid

Comment: . . It is a best practice to avoid.  However, I think the problem is most acute in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  SQL does not guarantee that the `WHERE` clause is executed "before" other clauses.  Filtering may occur before other operations.  Filtering may not.

This applies to CTEs and subqueries as well.  The SQL optimizer can re-arrange operations. SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  A query describes the result set, not how it is produced.

Your code seems to be SQL Server code.  If so, just use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead of `CONVERT()`.  If the conversion fails, the result is `NULL`, which fails most `WHERE`-clause comparisons.

Personally, I consider the behavior to be a bug -- type conversion errors on rows that are filtered out.  I do not know if the SQL standard has specifications on this subject.